# Как записывать объект в двумерный массив

Tags: javascript

Как записать в двумерный массив объект

```
var arr = [];

function Item(i, text, j)
{
    this.i = i;
    this.text = text;
    this.j = j;
}

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = new Item(2+i, 'text', 5+j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  // Перед началом цикла создавать массив, куда можно будет добавлять элементы

  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = new Item(2 + i, 5 + j, 'text');
  }
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2).replace(/{(.|\s)*?}/g, m => m.replace(/\s+/g,"")) );

/***/

function Item(i, j, text) {
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!